# Problem with AltTester Tool when importing in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, automation

I am learning more about AltTester in unity, but when I importing it. this error popped up but when checking the code every thing seems fine.

[image: This is the error when importing]

Also, still new to QA so please explain as simple as possible

Comment: Posting an image is encouraged if it helps understanding the issue better. But please don´t post code or error messages as images only. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). [edit] your question and add that information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import from package manager or add it manually to your manifest file. We explain this steps in our documentation https://altom.com/alttester/docs/sdk/pages/get-started.html#resolve-dependencies.